# wget, browsers not working after upgrade from 16.04 to 17.10 - dnslookup not working

Tags: ethernet

**Edit:**

My problem is that I cannot connect to the internet over my ethernet connection. When I run `wget http://google.com`, I get the error `...failed: Name or service not known.` Chrome and Firefox cannot load any sites citing connection problems.

The ethernet works fine when I plug in other computers. It's this specific machine that's not working.

**Edit 2 per comments from [chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555)**

```
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~$ wget --spider http://google.com
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2018-03-03 08:39:00--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘google.com’
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~$ ping -c3 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.56 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.69 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.66 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.568/1.642/1.695/0.071 ms
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=23.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=12.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=11.7 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.742/15.840/23.394/5.349 ms
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

lines 8-30
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (enp0s25)
lines 8-31
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (enp0s25)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
lines 8-32

                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (enp0s25)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
lines 8-33
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (enp0s25)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
~
lines 8-37/37 (END)

                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (enp0s25)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
~
~
lines 8-37/37 (END)
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (enp0s25)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (enp0s25)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
```

**Edit 3**

It's clearly a DNS lookup problem.

I found the IP address of google.com on another machine.

```
ping -c3 172.217.11.142
```

works with pings around 40 ms.

When I run `nslookup google.com`, I get `;; connection timed ou; no servers could be reached`

I attempted the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214170/whats-the-default-etc-network-interfaces) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380374/can-ping-but-cannot-wget-with-server-name) using DHCP and static to no benefit.

I first attempted with DHCP, then static

```
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~$ sudo ifdown enp0s25 && sudo ifp -v enp0s25
ifdown: interface enp0s25 not configured
sudo: ifp: command not found
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~$ sudo ifdown enp0s25 && sudo ifup -v enp0s25
ifdown: interface enp0s25 not configured

Configuring interface enp0s25=enp0s25 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant

/sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.enp0s25.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.enp0s25.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.enp0s25.leases enp0s25  
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s25/5c:f9:dd:70:17:f6
Sending on   LPF/enp0s25/5c:f9:dd:70:17:f6
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xe91bd312)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.10 on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x12d31be9)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.10 from 192.168.1.1
DHCPACK of 192.168.1.10 from 192.168.1.1
bound to 192.168.1.10 -- renewal in 42067 seconds.
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces #use static
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~$ sudo ifdown enp0s25 && sudo ifup -v enp0s25
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address

Configuring interface enp0s25=enp0s25 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
/bin/ip addr add 10.10.0.20/255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.10.0.255       dev enp0s25 label enp0s25
/bin/ip link set dev enp0s25   up
 /bin/ip route add default via 10.10.0.10  dev enp0s25 onlink 
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
/etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant
soverton@osr-ubuntu-2:~$ nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

**Original post**

I upgraded from 16.04 to 17.10 last night. Even before the reboot, the ethernet stopped working. When I go to the Network Manager and click "Auto ethernet", I see an image like this one pop up:
[image: connected]

and it immediately disconnects, similar to this image
[image: disconnects]

I've dug through many related posts, but none of the solutions worked for me.

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Edited to

[ifupdown]
managed=true

```
sudo service network-manager restart  #issue not resolved
```

Show my managed/unmanaged connections

```
nmcli d

DEVICE TYPE STATE CONNECTION
enp0s25 ethernet connectd Wired connection 1
lo loopback unmanaged
```

> sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

Edited to

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Restart network manager, still doesn't work

```
ifconfig

(I'm having to manually type this, I'm skipping over addresses)
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP, BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
     inet 192.168.1.8 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255
     inet6 fe80::5e1d:5c8:3898:bf5b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
     ether .... txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
     RX packets 10591 bytes 964576 (964.5 KB)
     RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
     TX packets 2499  bytes 258409 (258.4 KB)
     TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0  collisions 0
     device interrupt 20  memory ......

lo:  flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
     inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
     inet6  ::1  prefexlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
     loop  txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
     RX packets 17472  bytes 1624396 (1.6 MB)
     RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
     TX packets 17472  bytes 162396 (1.6 MB)
     TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`lsb_release -a` confirms I'm running 17.10

Comment: We are confused. Your title refers to ethernet. Your posts discusses wireless that immediately disconnects. Then your `ifconfig` clearly shows the ethernet has an IP address, and is receiving and transmitting packets, suggesting that it's working perfectly.  What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: When I open Chrome or Firefox, it can't open anything. If I run wget http://google.com, it says failed: Name or service not known.

Comment: Is your problem wireless or ethernet???

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `ping -c3 192.168.1.1` also: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` also: `systemd-resolve --status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolveconf
```

I discovered the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368435/how-do-i-fix-dns-resolving-which-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10-s#368935).

A friendly hat tip to chili555 for guiding me to the resolution.